# How to use a state to update multiple buttons

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I want that when I click a button, it shows more details, but I'd like to use a single state to update all the buttons individually. The issue is that when I click on one button, all of them update. How can I make it so that only one updates at a time using a state

```
const [mostrar,setMostrar] = useState(false);

const mostrarTodo =()=>{
setMostrar(!mostrar)
}
return (

<h2>FAQS</h2>

<h4>What is frontend mentor and how will help you?</h4>

{mostrar ? 'menos':'más'}
{mostrar && <p>
(Frontend Mentor is an online platform that provides web development challenges and projects for frontend developers of all levels to practice their skills. It offers a variety of mockups and designs for websites, allowing users to code and implement these designs using HTML, CSS, and JavaScript.)

</p>}

        </div>
        <div>  <h4>Is frontend mentor free?</h4>
        <button onClick={mostrarTodo}>
            {mostrar ? 'menos':'más'}
          </button>
        {mostrar && <p>yes</p>}
```

Comment: it would help if you provide a clear reproduction of the problem you're having - you can use codesandbox or stackblitz to create such a reproduction and share the link here - or at least provide a complete piece of code in your question

Comment: The point of those tasks is that you solve them yourself, not to simply ask other people to solve them for you

Comment: you can use `useContext` to manage your state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the index of the item to control the state instead of having a single state:

```
const items = [
  {
    question: 'What is frontend mentor...',
    answer: '(Detailed answer)',
    expanded: false  
  },
  {
    question: 'Is frontend mentor free?', 
    answer: 'yes',
    expanded: false
  }
]

const toggleFAQ = index => {
  const newItems = [...items];
  newItems[index].expanded = !newItems[index].expanded;
  setItems(newItems);
}

return (
  <div>
    {items.map((item, index) => (
      <>
        <h4>{item.question}</h4>

        <button onClick={() => toggleFAQ(index)}>
          {item.expanded ? 'Show Less' : 'Show More'}  
        </button>

        {item.expanded && <p>{item.answer}</p>}
      </>
    ))}
  </div>
)
```

Now each item maintains its own expanded state. When you toggle, it will only update that individual item.

Let me know if this helps explain an approach to solve your issue!

Comment: Or simply you can push index ids to a state array and then check on the state that if the id present in the state then expand otherwise not.